# Is there a library of higher compression ratio than UIImageJPEGRepresentation?

Tags: ios, compression, jpeg

Before sending the image to the server from the iOS App, App compressed JPG image with UIImageJPEGRepresentation. However, it is not a compression rate to expect.
Is there a library of higher compression ratio than UIImageJPEGRepresentation ?
（opencv? libjpeg?）

Thanks

2013.06.24 13:00 add

My Code is

```
NSData *jpgData = [[NSData alloc]    initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.75)];
```

Image size is reduced, but I want to reduce more.

Comment: Show the code that you are using.  My guess is that it looks something like this `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 80)` which is wrong.

Comment: I added my code. Appearance as it is, I want to reduce the image size more.

Comment: Everyone wants that, but it's not possible.  To get a smaller image size, you need to sacrifice quality.  That's how it works.

Comment: I understand that you said. Thanks.

Comment: Try setting quality to 10 - the image will still look pretty good.

Comment: If you don't need the full 8 megapixel image, definitely consider sizing it down before you compress it. You'll save a lot of space more easily starting with a downsampled image and compressing it, when compared with just fiddling with compression alone on the full size image.